# Console Error in $element, while using $mdDialog of AngularJS Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material, mddialog

I'm trying to solve this error that shows in the console, it only occurs on the server, in my localhost the modal works correctly. Here's the error (click to open its link):

[image]

I have a view with the controller:

```
.when('/aseguradora', {
    templateUrl: 'views/insuranceagentdashboard.html',
    controller: 'InsuranceagentdashboardCtrl'
})
```

This is the controller:

```
angular.module('virtualApp').controller('InsuranceagentdashboardCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', 'pager', 'Dialogs', function($http, $scope, pager, Dialogs) {..
```

Inside the controller I have a function that executes the modal, (Dialogs is a service):

```
$scope.showCosignerFormDialog = function(insuranceRequest) {
    Dialogs.cosignerFormdialog(insuranceRequest);
}
```

In HTML I have an `md-button` with an `ng-click`

```
<md-button class="md-color-green" ng-click="showCosignerFormDialog(insuranceRequest)">VER SOLICITUD</md-button>
```

This is the `Dialog` service that executes the modal:

```
dialogs.cosignerFormdialog = function(insuranceRequest) {
    return $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: 'views/cosignerformdialog.html',
        autoWrap: false,
        controller: 'IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl',
        locals: {
            listing: insuranceRequest
        },
        preserveScope: true,            
        escapeToClose: false,
        fullscreen: true,
        clickOutsideToClose: true
    });
};
```

I do not know why this error can occur in the console being in the URL of the server, if I am in my localhost I do not get this error ...

**THIS IS CONTROLLER** `identityverificationwizard.js`:

```
angular.module('virtualApp').controller('IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl', ['$scope', 'upload', '$http', 'listing', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Dialogs', '$element', function($scope, upload, $http, listing, $routeParams, $location, Dialogs, $element) {
    $scope.propertyListing = listing;
    $scope.insuranceStudyContactInfo = {};
    $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo = {};
    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo = {};
    $scope.insuranceStudyAssets = {};
    $scope.identityInfo = {
        date : moment('01/01/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate()
    };
    $scope.virtualSignatureInfo = {};
    $scope.isCorporation = 'false';
    $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.publicOfficer = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.managesPublicFunds = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.linkedToRenownedPeople = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.vatResponsible = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.greatContributor = false;

    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doImport = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doExport = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInvest = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doCurrencyExchange = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayServices = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayLoans = false;
    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doTransactions = false;

    $scope.rentProcessId = $scope.propertyListing.rentProcessId;
    $scope.cosignerKey = $location.search().cosignerKey;

    if ($scope.rentProcessId || $scope.cosignerKey) {
        $scope.readOnly = false;
    } else {
        $scope.readOnly = true;
    }

    $scope.setTabIndex = function(index) {
        $scope.tabIndex = index;
    }

    $scope.fileChanged = function(kind, file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            if (kind == 'front') {
                $scope.frontIdFile = file;
                $scope.frontIdImage = e.target.result;
                $scope.$apply();
            } else {
                $scope.backIdFile = file;
                $scope.backIdImage = e.target.result;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
        $scope.$apply();
    }

    $scope.uploadForm = function() {
        var params = {};

        if ($scope.insuranceStudyContactInfo.city) {
            $scope.insuranceStudyContactInfo.cityCode = $scope.insuranceStudyContactInfo.city.cityCode;
        }

        if ($scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.city) {
            $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.cityCode = $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo.city.cityCode;
        }
        if ($scope.insuranceStudyAssets.hasProperties) {
            if ($scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property1 && $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property1.city) {
                $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property1.cityCode = $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property1.city.cityCode || null;
            } else {
                delete $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property1;
            }

            if ($scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property2 && $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property2.city) {
                $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property2.cityCode = $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property2.city.cityCode || null;
            } else {
                delete $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property2;
            }
        } else {
            delete $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property1;
            delete $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property2;
        }

        if ($scope.propertyListing.rentProcessId) {
            params.rentProcessId = $scope.propertyListing.rentProcessId;
        }

        if ($location.search().cosignerKey) {
            params.cosignerKey = $location.search().cosignerKey;
        }

        if ($scope.identityInfo.date) {
            $scope.identityInfo.birthDate = formatedDate($scope.identityInfo.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
        }
        $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doImport = $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doImport || false;
        $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doExport = $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doExport || false;
        $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInvest = $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInvest || false;
        $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doCurrencyExchange = $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doCurrencyExchange || false;
        $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayServices = $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayServices || false;
        $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayLoans = $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayLoans || false;
        $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doTransactions = $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doTransactions || false;

        params.isCorporation = $scope.isCorporation;
        params.contactInfo = JSON.stringify($scope.insuranceStudyContactInfo);
        params.jobInfo = JSON.stringify($scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo);
        params.financialInfo = JSON.stringify($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo);
        params.assets = JSON.stringify($scope.insuranceStudyAssets);
        params.virtualSignatureInfo = JSON.stringify($scope.virtualSignatureInfo);
        params.identityInfo = JSON.stringify($scope.identityInfo);

    $scope.isReadOnly = function() {
        if ($scope.readOnly) {
            $http.get(root + "Insurance/s/getInsuranceRequest", {
                params: {
                    insuranceRequestId: $scope.propertyListing.insuranceRequestId
                }
            }).then(function(res) {
                $scope.code = res.data.code;
                $scope.type = res.data.type;
                $scope.datetime = res.data.datetime;
                $scope.status = res.data.status;
                $scope.listingCode = res.data.listingCode;
                $scope.isCorporation = res.data.corporation + "";
                $scope.identityInfo.documentTypeCode = res.data.identityInfo.documentTypeCode;
                $scope.identityInfo.documentNumber = res.data.identityInfo.documentNumber;
                $scope.identityInfo.names = res.data.identityInfo.names;
                $scope.identityInfo.lastNames = res.data.identityInfo.lastNames;
                $scope.identityInfo.date = res.data.identityInfo.birthDate;
                $scope.insuranceStudyContactInfo = res.data.contactInfo;
                $scope.insuranceStudyJobInfo = res.data.jobInfo;
                $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo = res.data.financialInfo;

                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.foreignAccountBank) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doForeignAccount = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.foreignAccount) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doForeignAccount = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.foreignAccountCurrency) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doForeignAccount = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.foreignAccountCountry) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doForeignAccount = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.foreignAccountCity) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doForeignAccount = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doImport) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInternationalOperations = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doExport) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInternationalOperations = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInvest) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInternationalOperations = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doCurrencyExchange) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInternationalOperations = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayServices) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInternationalOperations = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doPayLoans) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInternationalOperations = true;
                }
                if ($scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doTransactions) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyFinancialInfo.doInternationalOperations = true;
                }


                $scope.insuranceStudyAssets = res.data.assets;

                if ($scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property1 || $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.property2) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.hasProperties = true;
                }

                if ($scope.insuranceStudyAssets.vehicle1 || $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.vehicle2) {
                    $scope.insuranceStudyAssets.hasCars = true;
                }

                $scope.availableActions = res.data.availableActions;
            });
        }
    }
    $scope.isReadOnly();
}]);
```

Comment: post the code of your `IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl` controller.

Comment: @OmarEinea Ok, It's right.

Comment: Why are you injecting `$element` into your controller? I don't see it being used inside it. Try removing it and see if the issue is gone.

Comment: I already tried, but the problem is still @OmarEinea

Comment: Have you tried `angular.module('virtualApp').controller('IdentityVerificatio‌​nWizardCtrl', ['$scope', 'upload', '$http', 'listing', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Dialogs', function($scope, upload, $http, listing, $routeParams, $location, Dialogs) {` removing `$element` ?

Comment: @Durga Yes, I have tried

Comment: If you are removing that both `$element`, then you wont get that error I guess, cause no where elese you are injecting `$element`

Comment: can it be some permission inside the server? what do you think? @Durga

Comment: @Pablo did you check (in the browser inspect) that all JS files are loaded? as the problem seems server related.

Comment: all JS files, they are compiled into one. I`m using Grunt. @OmarEinea

Comment: @Pablo and you're using it on both localhost and server? are there any differences between localhost and server that you think might cause the problem?

Comment: @OmarEinea yes, I do not know what may be failing... :(

Comment: already solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: @Pablo Can you add what solved the problem as an answer to this post and mark it is accepted, this way future users who stumble across this issue will find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error says your are using an *unknown dependency* in your controller.
Here, the error says that the "*unknown dependency*" is a provider called **$element**.

! There are 3 types of providers in angularjs: **service, factory or provider**

2 reasons why you can have this problem:

1) If you don't have any providers (service, factory or provider) called **$element** in your project you shouldn't have a dependency for it.
In *IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl*

Instead of:

```
.controller('IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl', ['$scope', 'upload', '$http', 'listing', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Dialogs', '$element', function($scope, upload, $http, listing, $routeParams, $location, Dialogs, $element)
```

Write:

```
.controller('IdentityVerificationWizardCtrl', ['$scope', 'upload', '$http', 'listing', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Dialogs', function($scope, upload, $http, listing, $routeParams, $location, Dialog)
```

2) if you have a provider called $element , maybe you didn't call it into your index.html

PS: In angularjs, $element is a parametter used into the link function and refer to the DOM element. So IMO opinion your error is because of reason 1